# Array reshape not mapping correctly to numpy meshgrid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a long 121 element array where the data is stored in ascending order and I want to reshape to an 11x11 matrix and so I use the NumPy reshape command

```
Z = data.attributevalue[2,time,axial,:]
Z = np.reshape(Z, (int(math.sqrt(datacount)), int(math.sqrt(datacount))))
```

The data should be oriented in a Cartesian plane and I create the mesh grid with the following

```
x = np.arange(1.75, 12.5, 1)
y = np.arange(1.75, 12.5, 1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
```

The issue is that rows of Z are in the wrong order so the data in the last row of the matrix should be in the first and vice-versa. I want to rearrange so the rows are filled in the proper manner. The starting array Z is assembled in the following arrangement [datapoint #1, datapoint #2 ...., datapoint #N]. Datapoint #1 should  be in the top left and the last point in the bottom right. Is there a simple way of accomplishing this or do I have to make a function to changed the order of the rows?

my plot statement is the following

```
surf = self.ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet,
    linewidth=1, antialiased=True)
```

***UPDATE****

I tried populating the initial array backwards and still no luck. I changed the orientation of the axis to the following

```
y = np.arrange(12.5,1,-1)
```

This flipped the data but my axis label is wrong so it is not a real solution to my issue. Any ideas?

Comment: @OlehPrypin I updated my posting to be clear, my code works but it is not doing what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that your original array does not look like a 1x121 array. The following code block shows how you reshape an array from 1x121 to 11x11.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(1,122)
print A
print A.reshape((11,11))
```

Gives:

```
[  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18 19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36 37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54 55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72 73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90 91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121]

[[  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11]
 [ 12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22]
 [ 23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33]
 [ 34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44]
 [ 45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55]
 [ 56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66]
 [ 67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77]
 [ 78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88]
 [ 89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99]
 [100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110]
 [111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121]]
```

Comment: Do I need to slip in an arrange command. The starting data array is assembled as [1,2,...] but i am not getting the bottom array as you have shown. Thanks for the quick reply.